# heroku config PATH variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, dependencies

I'm trying to deploy a heroku app that depends on an unsupported external library. I loaded the library into my vendor folder but now I need to configure heroku to look in a specific path for dependencies. From reading around I believe I need to use `heroku config:set PATH=xxx` but I do not know how to use this variable. What would I need to put there if I want heroku to include `vendor/includes` and `vendor/bin` when looking for dependencies?